# Hyperledger Fabric: "The clientContext has not been properly initialized, missing userContext" error

Tags: hyperledger

I am trying to send multiple transactions concurrently and I received an error saying "The clientContext has not been properly initialized, missing userContext" from time to time. No matter I am sending as one client or two clients, the same problem occurs. I have attached a screenshot to display the problem. Thank you very much [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VGPm.png)

Comment: Even I am stuck with the same error. :(